# Alternative ways of passing PS1 env variable into Ubuntu for SSH session

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, environment-variables, prompt

*I know that there are twenty thousand answers, none of them worked as expected, I'm more surprised than you are, so please consider reading the story first.*

I'm trying to achieve what appears to be a basic thing: send local `PS1` variable to Ubuntu 14.04.1 when I'm SSH'ing into it from a Mac. I know there are two ways of doing it:

1. Using the SendEnv directive inside /etc/ssh_config,
2. Using a command with SSH, something like `ssh host -t "PS1='"$PS1"'; exec bash"`.

Both routes decently well described in other SE answers and there are plenty of results on Google. But none seem to work for me as expected.

The first option doesn't work, I did set `AcceptEnv PS1` and `PermitUserEnvironment yes` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config in Ubuntu. If I try to pass any other variable, it works as expected. I've looked into `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` and it seems to have a lot of `PS1` assignments. Does it get redefined there and if it does, how to prevent this from happening?

The second option doesn't work either, but again, it works with any other variable name. If I do `export ABC=123; exec bash` on SSH login, I can see `ABC` in the defined variables, if I do the same with `PS1`, it always defaults to `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`. Another problem with the second solution is that some environment variables are not loaded when I run `exec bash`, I tried with `--login` and `--interactive` options, tried to source `. ~/.profile` and `. ~/.bashrc`, but I don't get the same output on login (Ubuntu banner and stats) when I get logged in and variables remain undefined (so as aliases and other useful stuff I assume?).

I want to know how to set my prompt styles defined in local `PS1` onto a recent Ubuntu on SSH connection. **Changing PS1-related configuration on Ubuntu is NOT an option**, I explicitly want to pass the configuration from my client, so I don't do the same thing twenty times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've looked into `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` and it seems to have a lot of `PS1` assignments. Does it get redefined there and if it does, how to prevent this from happening?

Yes, it gets redefined. Both your methods set the variable initially, but it doesn't matter once `bash` sources any file that redefines `PS1`.

To prevent this from happening you

- either make the remote `bash` detect if you're connected with `ssh` and not change `PS1` in this case; this may require massive changes to those sourced files and you don't want to do this;
- or let the remote `bash` set `PS1` in any way it currently does, but override it *at the very end*; this seems to be a way better method.

Add the following line at the end of your `.bashrc` on the remote machine:

```
[ -n "$PS1_ovrrde" ] && PS1="$PS1_ovrrde"
```

Now all you have to do is setting `PS1_ovrrde` on the remote side when you log in via SSH. You already know two ways. Notes:

1. With `SendEnv` you need `PS1_ovrrde` to be in your local environment, I think. Add `export PS1_ovrrde="$PS1"` at the end of your local `.bashrc`.
2. With `exec bash` you need to export `PS1_ovrrde` to the remote environment: `ssh host -t "export PS1_ovrrde=..."`. Variables already in the remote environment don't need to be exported again, but here you're creating a brand new variable.